# Kubernetes: Host 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, ansible

I am spinning up a MYSQL container on a K8s cluster. The deployment yaml is as follow:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{ ca.name }}-db-mysql
  labels:
    k8s-app: {{ ca.name }}-db-mysql
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ ca.name }}-db-mysql
      image: "mysql:5.7.23"
      env:
        - { name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", value: "password" }
        - { name: "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST", value: "%" }
      args: ["mysqld", --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password", "--sql-mode="]
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
      volumeMounts:
        - { mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql", name: "{{ ca.name }}-mysql", subPath: "cas/db/rca/mysqldb" }
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  volumes:
    - name: {{ ca.name }}-mysql
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ ca.name }}-mysql-volume
```

Despite of using **MYSQL_ROOT_HOST** configuration, the configured pod doesn't gets it's host configured as **%** for the root user.

[image]

I have to manually update the host settings to access MYSQL container outside the cluster.

```
kubectl exec -it ca1st-orgb-db-mysql /bin/bash
mysql -u root
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Why it doesn't gets configured with the default setting which is being provided in the environment variables? Could someone can share their thoughts on this.

Comment: Looking at the docs, https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, section Environment Variables: "Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database". Is it the case?

Comment: I am deleting and re-creating PVC volumes before spinning up DB pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue with MYSQL **image 5.7.23**. I **downgraded MYSQL version to 5.6 and removed args** from pod configuration and everything works as expected.

DB Queries:

1. Start a MYSQL client: `kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:5.7.23 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h ca1st-orga-db-mysql -pyourpassword`
2. Run SELECT query on User: `SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';`

You can notice `%` along with localhost.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: @MWZ Thanks for sharing this. I will keep this in mind. I used a screenshot just to display the output of the query from DB. Updated the answers with the queries I ran.